# How to associate a form object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save a Form Object in Rails through and association like this:

```
document.translations_forms.save(translation_params)
```

And on my Document model I associated it this way:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :translations_forms
  ...
end
```

But when I run the first command above, I getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Document::TranslationsForm:Class
```

I tried declaring the TranslationFrom Object adding the Document namespace

```
class Document::TranslationsForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  belongs_to :document

  def save(params: {})
    return false if invalid?

    self.document.translation.create(params)
  end
end
```

But didn't work either, my TranslationForm object is in the `app/forms/translations_form.rb` directory, and I'm using `rails 6`, what can I do to associate the model with my form object?

Comment: `Document` is inheriting from `ApplicationRecord`, `TranslationsForms` does not, I don't want to persist it on the database, I just want to use some validators before passing it to the `Translation` model

Answer (score 1):

A form object (which is a vague term) is usually just a variation of the Decorator pattern.

So you could simply setup the form object so that it wraps an instance of the model class:

```
class Document
  class TranslationForm
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attribute_reader :document

    def initialize(record = nil, attributes = {})
      # lets you use the form object for existing records
      if record 
        @document = record 
        @document.assign_attributes(attributes)
      end
      @document ||= Document.new(attributes)
    end

    def to_model
      document
    end

    def save
      # triggers validations on the form object
      if valid?
        document.save     
      else
        false
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

```
def create
  @document = Document::TranslationForm.new(document_params)
  if @document.save
    redirect_to @document
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

```
def update
  @document = Document::TranslationForm.new(
    Document.find(params[:id]),
    document_params
  )
  if @document.save
    redirect_to @document
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

To add a validation to the form object (instead of directly to the model) just use delegatation:

```
class Document
  class TranslationForm
    # ...
    validates :foo, presence: true
    delegate :errors, to: :document
    delegate :foo, to: :document
  end
end
```

`delegate :errors, to: :document` makes it so that your validations will add errors to the underlying model instead of the errors object of your form object.

Comment: This kind of assumes a simple scenario where the form object has the same attributes and only wraps a single model. YMMV for more complex scenarios.